# Can't get Wordpress Database Query to work

Tags: mysql, wordpress, buddypress

I am trying to get this Query to work but something must be wrong with my query. I can pull all the data out but can't figure out how to pull out data that matches a specific username. This is built on wordpress with buddypress integration.

```
global $wpdb;
$ttm_username = bp_get_displayed_user_fullname();

$trackingData = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_shipping_numbers` WHERE `username` = $ttm_username ");
```

Comment: Are you getting the username from this function `bp_get_displayed_user_fullname()`?

Comment: yes, I can insert into the table and pull all the data from it but I dont have much backend experience so Im not sure if Im querying right...

Comment: I inserted using that function as well so I know it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting the username with `bp_get_displayed_user_fullname()` function, that returns you as a string value.

```
$wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT * FROM `wp_shipping_numbers` WHERE `username` = $ttm_username "
);
```

Use

```
$wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT * FROM `wp_shipping_numbers` WHERE `username` = '".$ttm_username."' "
);
```

Comment: Ok I see I was close I knew it was something with that part just didn't know how to do it in a query. Thanks so much, worked perfect:)

Answer (score 1):

You are placing `$ttm_username` in your string as text, and not a string.  So that needs to be fixed. Also, to save headaches in formatting & debugging, I do the following: I like to use single quotes to delineate strings. And I like to break up queries into easier to digest “per line” chunks when setting in a string.

```
global $wpdb;
$ttm_username = bp_get_displayed_user_fullname();

$query = 'SELECT *'
       . ' FROM `wp_shipping_numbers`'
       . ' WHERE `username` = ' . $ttm_username
       ;
$trackingData = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```